# zipped data shown in view but not in templete

Tags: python-3.x, django

row1 = []
row2 = []

```
categories= Kategoriler.objects.all().filter(parent_id__isnull=True).order_by('id')
for x in categories:
    row1.append(x.title)
    row2.append(Kategoriler.objects.all().filter(parent_id=x.id).order_by('title'))

zipped = itertools.zip_longest(row1, row2)


for u, y in zipped:
    print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", u, "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")
    for q in y:
        print(q.title)


context = {'segment': 'categories', "zipped": zipped}
```

Above code prints as expected in view.py

In templete;

```
{{ zipped|length }}
                {%  for u, y in zipped %}
                    {{ u }}---{{ y.title }}
                {%  endfor %}
```

len gives 0, and loop is empty.
What's the reason of it?

Comment: When you iterate over `zipped` in the view it is completely consumed and will no longer yield values. Can you just remove the prints or convert to a list first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *not* enumerate over `zip` in the view, since that will "consume" the iterator, and then the iterator is thus "exhausted". You pass `zipped` to the view without enumerating, so:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

row1 = []
row2 = []
categories = Kategoriler.objects.filter(parent=None).order_by('id')
for x in categories:
    row1.append(x.title)
    row2.append(Kategoriler.objects.filter(parent_id=x.id).order_by('title')

zipped = zip_longest(row1, row2)
# no enumeration
context = {'segment': 'categories', "zipped": zipped}
```

In the template you can then render with:

```
{% for u, ys in zipped %}
    {% for y in ys %}
        {{ u }}---{{ y.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You should *not* use `{{ zipped|length }}` since this will *again* consume the zipper.

That being said, the zipping is *unnecessary* and *inefficient*: it will make *N+1* queries if `categories` contains *N* elements. You can fetch the items with:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

categories = Kategoriler.objects.filter(
    parent=None
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('kategoriler_set', Kategoriler.objects.order_by('title'))
).order_by('id')
context = {'segment': categories}
```

In the template you can then render this with:

```
{% for segment in segment %}
    {% for sub in segment.kategoriler_set.all %}
        {{ segment.title }}---{{ sub.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you set a [**`related_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for the `ForeignKey` named `parent`, then you should replace `kategoriler_set` with that value.